# Picture Clicked from default camera not getting saved with proper orientation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

Iam trying to capture a picture using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
```

but when i get the result, the orientation of the picture is not proper in most of the cases. Since I need to use the picture at a number of places, so I want the picture to be saved with the proper orientation. How can this be done?

Doubt : 
1. Doesn't android default camera itself take care of the orientation when saving picture?
2. DO I have to use "ExifInterface" tweak every time when I display the picture from local?

Answer (score 0):

> the orientation of the picture is not proper in most of the cases

That depends on your opinion of what is "proper". Various device manufacturers and camera apps believe that having an EXIF orientation tag is perfectly proper.

> How can this be done?

You are welcome to scan the image for the EXIF header and rotate the image yourself, but this is slow and memory-intensive.

> 1. Doesn't android default camera itself take care of the orientation when saving picture?

First, you are not necessarily using any "android default camera". Any camera app can respond to your `Intent`. There are thousands of device models, with hundreds of pre-installed camera apps, let alone apps that users might get from the Play Store or elsewhere.

Second, as noted above, some developers feel that "take care of the orientation" is having the appropriate EXIF header.

> 2. DO I have to use "ExifInterface" tweak every time when I display the picture from local?

Well, that depends. You could convert it once and save the converted image, then use the converted one going forward, rather than converting it every time. Whether or not it is appropriate for you to saving a converted image or not is up to you and your users.